# Request with explanation of the given property of cosets.

Tags: group-theory

Taken from the book: Groups for Undergraduates, by John Atwell Moody.

1.2 Proposition. Let $a$ and $b$ be natural numbers. Let $e$ be their gcd. Suppose there exists an $a$-element group $G$ with exactly $f \ e$-element subgroups. Then
$$\binom{a}{b}=f\cdot \binom{a/e}{b/e}+m(a/e).$$
where $m$ is a linear combination ($=$ sum with possibly repeated terms) of divisors of $e,$ not including $1.$

Doubt #1: Kindly tell some example of groups,  where can find (calculate) $m.$

The proof on page #12 states:
Recall that $Hg = Hhg,$ for any $h\in H.$

Doubt #2: Please state why $Hg = Hhg,$ for any $h\in H,$ with an example.

[image: Page #11]
[image: Page #12]
[image: Page #13]

Comment: The overuse of images shows that this is a poorly crafted question. Posts should not need to rely on images, and certainly not on copying 3 pages of a book in order to give "context".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your doubt 2, let me illustrate with the following example. Take $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=5\mathbb{Z}$. The statement we want to show is for any number $p,n\in \mathbb{Z}$, we have (recalling that the group operation is addition in this case)
$$5\mathbb{Z}+n=5\mathbb{Z}+5m+n$$
Recall for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $S\subset \mathbb{Z}$, we define $S+x:=\{s+x:s\in S\}$. We therefore compute
\begin{align*} 
5\mathbb{Z}+5m+n&=\{5p+5m+n:p\in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
&=\{5(p+m)+n:p\in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
&=\{5q+n:q\in \mathbb{Z} \}\\
&=5\mathbb{Z}+n
\end{align*}
The second to last equality follows from the fact that for each $q\in \mathbb{Z}$, we can uniquely solve the equation
$$q=p+m$$
for fixed $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. This example also gives more or less a proof of the general statement if you do the proper conversion. The key idea in the general case is $Hh=H$ for $h\in H$, namely elements of $H$ act as bijections on $H$ by right multiplication. In our case, this is evidenced by $5\mathbb{Z}+5m=5\mathbb{Z}$. Geometrically, this translates all elements of $5\mathbb{Z}$ by $5m$, which is clearly a bijection as you can just shift back by $-5m$.